# Responsive layout design issue with FireFox re-size window

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I use [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) version 3.2.3 in a website design. It works perfect on Chrome but there is an issue with FireFox represented in the attached screen shot image. Simply, when I re-size the browser's window to some small width, In FirFox, some parts of the right hand-side does not be shown as you see in the image below. Also the vertical scroll bar in FireFox is disappeared.

The following is the code of the page's head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  dir="rtl"  lang="ar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
  <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/quran/themed/slate/css/imports.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/quran/themed/slate/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>



    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <![endif]-->


    <!-- IE Fix for HTML5 Tags -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

    <![endif]-->
<title></title>
```

**It is FireFox version: 16.0.2 on Windows 7 64 bit with screen resolution 1366 x 768.**

I need to know how to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug in FireFox 16.0.2, when I upgraded the browser to version 17.0. It works fine like shown in the following screen shot:

[image]